# How to prevent Sequelize from summarizing / reducing result (distict) when including additional association?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm currently working on a game in which a player can have many cards and a card belongs to many players. Also the player can have the same card many times with a different card order. Additionally a card has many CardTranslations.

If I'm selecting all cards of a player with `player.getCards()` the result is correct and the "same" card is displayed multiple times (with the corresponding card order).

[Correct result - same card multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enDty.png)

But if I include an additional association like the CardTranslation `player.getCards({include: [{model:db.models.CardTranslation, as: 'cardTranslations'}]})` the result gets reduced so that each card only appears once.
However, I would expect the same 20 cards as before, but each card instance should also have the CardTranslations on it.

[Wrong result - same card only once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxST7.png)

It looks like Sequelize applied internally something similar like a "distinct" when building the models. (the database query is correct both times correct).

**Why does Sequelize behave like this and can this behaviour be prevented without losing the model-functionalities or is there an error on my side that I don't recognize?**

**Card**

```
'use strict';
import { Model } from 'sequelize';
module.exports = (sequelize: any, DataTypes: any) => {
  class Card extends Model {

    static associate(models: any) {

      Card.belongsToMany(models.Player, {
        through: {
          model: models.Card_Player,
          unique: false
        },
      });
      Card.hasMany(models.CardTranslation, {
        as: {
          singular: 'cardTranslation',
          plural: 'cardTranslations'
        }, foreignKey: 'card_id'
      });
    }
  }
  Card.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'Card',
    modelName: 'Card',
  });
  return Card;
};
```

**Player**

```
'use strict';
import { Model } from 'sequelize';
module.exports = (sequelize: any, DataTypes: any) => {
  class Player extends Model {
    static associate(models: any) {

      Player.belongsToMany(models.Card, {
        through: {
          model: models.Card_Player,
          unique: false
        },
      });
    }
  }
  Player.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'Player',
    modelName: 'Player',
  });
  return Player;
};
```

**Card_Player**

```
'use strict';
import { Model } from 'sequelize';
module.exports = (sequelize: any, DataTypes: any) => {
  class Card_Player extends Model { //it represents the shuffeled cards (deck) of a player
    static associate(models: any) {
    }
  }
  Card_Player.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    cardOrder: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, field: 'card_order'},
    status: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'Card_Player',
    modelName: 'Card_Player',
  });
  return Card_Player;
};
```

**CardTranslation**

```
'use strict';
import { Model } from 'sequelize';
module.exports = (sequelize: any, DataTypes: any) => {
  class CardTranslation extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models: any) {
      // define association here
      CardTranslation.belongsTo(models.Card, { as: 'card', foreignKey: 'card_id' });
    }

  }
  CardTranslation.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    language: DataTypes.STRING,
    cardGraphic: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, field: 'card_graphic' },

  }, {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
    tableName: 'CardTranslation',
    modelName: 'CardTranslation',
  });
  return CardTranslation;
};
```

Comment: Did you look at generated SQL in both cases?

Comment: Yes, both SQLs return 20 rows.

Comment: How many cards have card transitions? All of them?

Comment: Yes. I get the translations for each different card, but each card only once.
Like: 
`CardA.Translations with CardA.Card_Player.cardOrder A
CardB.Translations with CardB.Card_Player.cardOrder B
..

But it should be:
CardA.Translations with CardA.Card_Player.cardOrder A
CardA.Translations with CardA.Card_Player.cardOrder X
CardA.Translations with CardA.Card_Player.cardOrder Y
CardA.Translations with CardA.Card_Player.cardOrder Z

CardB.Translations with CardB.Card_Player.cardOrder B`
...

If I use the option "raw:true" the result is correct.

Comment: Weird. Maybe a bug in Sequelize